# Gluon curly upside down

Tags: feynmp

I am drawing some feynman diagrams and for stylistic purposes I would like to have the gluon curly upside-down (the way the gluon attaches to the vertex is somehow 
ugly.
Looking in online drawers that use feynmf (from these you can copy the tex code)
I see that there is the option `{directions = $-1$}` when creating the gluon line..
I tried the same command in feynmp (and feynmp-auto) but nothing happened.

Does anyone know if such an option is implemented in feynmp?

Davide

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{fmffile}{qgComp}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,110)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o2}
\fmf{gluon}{i2,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,o1}
\fmflabel{g}{i2}
\fmflabel{q}{i1}
\fmflabel{q}{o2}
\fmflabel{$\gamma$}{o1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v2}
\fmfforce{(.5w,.25h)}{v1}
\fmfforce{(.5w,.75h)}{v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Working Example of what you have tried so far? Without, everyone here trying to help you would need to create a FeynMP example by himself. So help us to help you by providing a MWE! :)

Comment: Hi, apologies, I have edited the question with a MWE that shows how bad the gluon line connects to the vertex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy: just revert the direction of the gluon:

```
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v2,o2}
\fmf{gluon}{v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,o1}
\fmflabel{g}{i2}
\fmflabel{q}{i1}
\fmflabel{q}{o2}
\fmflabel{$\gamma$}{o1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v2}
\fmfforce{(.5w,.25h)}{v1}
\fmfforce{(.5w,.75h)}{v2}
```

I only include the feynmp code.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, this indeed was the command I was looking for, unfortunately not the result I had hoped for... Oh well, I will have to live with one of the two..

Comment: I usually put dots on the vertices, `fmfdot{v1,v2}` in your case, because I like the result better...